# C# double as reference?

Tags: c#, reference, double

I have my own class using the MathDotNet package (more precisely, the `Vector<double>` class from namespace MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra). The `Vector<double>` class has a method

```
public double At(int index)
```

that returns the double value of the specified index. Internally, the `Vector<double>` class uses a `double[]` for that storage. I think it is not possible to directly access the internal `double[]`.

```
class TwoVectors
{
    private Vector<double> v1, v2;

    // initializes the vectors v1 and v2, both have length 2.
    public TwoVectors(double[] entries1, double[] entries2)
    {
        if (entries1 == null || entries2 == null ||
            entries1.Length != 2 || entries2.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Erroneous input!");

        v1 = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(entries1);
        v2 = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(entries2);
    }

    // gives a copy of the vector data.
    public double[] ArrayData
    {
        get
        {
            return new double[] { v1.At(0), v1.At(1), v2.At(0), v2.At(1) };
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like the Getter not to return a copy of the vector data but the actual vector data, so that future changes are reflected in the vectors.

I.e. if I call

```
public static Main()
{
    TwoVectors twoVec = new TwoVectors(new double[] {1, 2}, new double[] {3, 4});
    twoVec.ArrayData[0] = 42;
    double[] arrayData = mc.ArrayData;  // this now contains {1, 2, 3, 4}
}
```

then I would like arrayData to contain {42, 2, 3, 4} instead of {1, 2, 3, 4}, as it does now.

I believe I can do this with pointers, but I don't know how!
I thought I could write

```
public double[] ArrayData
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe { return new double*[] { &v1.At(0), &v1.At(1), &v2.At(0), &v2.At(1) }; }
        }
    }
```

but the compiler tells me that the address of v1.At(0) and the other ones could not be gotten (Why?).
Also with pointers, I guess I cannot write stuff like

```
twoVec.ArrayData[0] = 42;
double[] arrayData = mc.ArrayData;
```

but something with * or & or ->, so there must be some other way... Any ideas?

PS: I know I can write an indexer for my class that looks something like this:

```
public double this[int i]
{
    set
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: v1.At(0, value); break;
            case 1: v1.At(1, value); break;
            case 2: v2.At(0, value); break;
            case 3: v2.At(1, value); break;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index must range from 0 to 3!");
        }
    }
}
```

(with method `Vector<double>.At(int index, double value)` being the setter counterpart to the getter method from the top of the thread)
BUT I want to know if there is a direct way to make statements like

```
twoVec.ArrayData[0] = 42;
```

work as expected (i.e. make a real change in the vectors).

Comment: You would write your `this` indexer as the next-to-last code example, that's how you would do this.

Comment: It seems like this class has been written to be immutable. So if you want to change a value, you need to make a new Vector with the values you want (or use a different class :) ).

Comment: I wonder if you could define the type as: `Vector<double?>`.  The array would now be of types rather than values.

Comment: Great idea! (I would upvote your comment if I had enough reputation.) Unfortunately, the `Vector<T>` class does not support nullable types for `T`.

Comment: I would go a route like Spivonious suggested, but perhaps just some caching proxy to the Vector class, not a whole new implementation.

Comment: This isn't going anywhere.  Beyond the significant language obstacles, the Vector class doesn't help at all either.  Storage is virtualized, may be dense or sparse.